# EpisodeDetailsRouteArgs can not be null because it has a required parameter

Tags: flutter, routes, router

I got  **EpisodeDetailsRouteArgs can not be null because it has a required parameter** this error, even I passed the arguments.

Here my inkwell widget:

```
   onTap: () {
              AutoRouter.of(context).replace(EpisodeDetailsRoute(
                podcastImageUrl: podcastImageUrl,
                podcastName: podcastName,
                podcastOwner: podcastOwner,
                podcastEpisodes: podcastEpisodes,
              ));
            },
```

my router:

```
@MaterialAutoRouter(
  replaceInRouteName: 'Page,Route',
  routes: <AutoRoute>[
    AutoRoute(page: IntroductionPage),
    AutoRoute(
      page: LoginPage,
    ),
    AutoRoute(page: HomePage),
    AutoRoute(page: EpisodeDetailsPage, initial: true),
  ],
)
class $AppRouter {}
```

my EpisodeDetailsPage:

```
class EpisodeDetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const EpisodeDetailsPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.podcastImageUrl,
    required this.podcastName,
    required this.podcastOwner,
    required this.podcastEpisodes,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String podcastImageUrl;
  final String podcastName;
  final String podcastOwner;
  final String podcastEpisodes;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold();
  }
}
```

I use the latest version of auto_route. Can you help me ?

Comment: I also try constant string like "test", still it give an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and we will respond to this question based on my problem.

The error comes from the router file and the initial parameter.

Router file, here PageSplashScreen has the type initial because it is the first screen that will appear on the app and do not needs any args because it is an initial page:

```
@MaterialAutoRouter(
  replaceInRouteName: 'Page,Route',
  routes: <AutoRoute>[
    AutoRoute<dynamic>(
      page: PageSplashScreen,
      path: '/',
      initial: true,
    ),
    AutoRoute<dynamic>(
      page: PageCapsule,
      path: capsulePath,
      children: homeTabRouter,
    ),
  ],
)
```

So if we place the problem on the sub routers, if the initial is set at true auto_route will expect no arguments even if some are required. So you just need to remove the initial: true on the pages that are not initial and need to receive arguments. Like below.

Current homeTabRouter varibale:

```
const homeTabRouter = [
  AutoRoute<dynamic>(
    path: 'firstPage',
    page: FirstPage,
    initial: true,
  ),
  AutoRoute<dynamic>(
    path: 'secondPage',
    page: SecondPage,
    initial: true,
  ),
];
```

After modification, homeTabRouter varibale :

```
const homeTabRouter = [
  AutoRoute<dynamic>(
    path: 'firstPage',
    page: FirstPage,
  ),
  AutoRoute<dynamic>(
    path: 'secondPage',
    page: SecondPage,
  ),
];
```

So now if you wanted to pass parameters from CapsulePage to FirstPage or SecondPage it is possible because they're not initial anymore.

Comment: Hello, 
In the below, I realized that I changed the initial route, and the problem has been solved. Today, I faced this problem again, and I realized the below answer is totally wrong. Your suggestion is fine and works as well. I am just wondering about how the router decides the initial page if we do not set the initial one. @Da2ny

Comment: How is removing the initial route the solution here? What if I need the route to be initial and still have required arguments?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue too, I needed my widget key to be nullable, what I did was that I had to remove the const keyword from the widget constructor.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).